# Use Glimpse with self-hosting

Tags: mono, nancy, self-hosting, glimpse

Is it possible to use Glimpse with a self-hosted web application? Specifically, I'm trying to use Glimpse with Nancy (self-hosted) on Mono.

The only information that I'm able to find is about Glimpse within ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

Work is currently underway to make this possible.

Glimpse is getting very close to a v2 RC, when that is released then we will also be ready to push out a release of the Glimpse.Nancy integration being built here https://github.com/csainty/Glimpse.Nancy/tree/glimpse-20

I can't yet comment on Mono support as I have not tried it, but I will make an issue to make sure it is considered.

Comment: In terms of mono this isn't something that we have tested yet on v2. Its something that we would love to see where we are at. So if you get a chance, it would be great if you could try out the new bits so we can get an idea where we are at.

Comment: Glimpse 2.0 Beta is out.  What about this project?  The URL above is not valid but I did find the old? code here: https://github.com/csainty/Glimpse.Nancy